# Parcel set page base url

Tags: html, github-pages, parceljs

Im trying to make my react project work with gh pages, the images are not found for some reason, but on localhost it works, `<img alt="Vector" src="/img/vector-4.svg" />`

I've tried to add public-url `parcel build --public-url /standly.github.io/my-newsite/` or `/my-newsite/` but is still not working